# Fedora 11 trac authentication problems

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, trac

I am currently setting up trac on Fedora 11 using the rpm provided by Fedora. I have everything up and running except authentication. Any time I try to Login I get the error "Authentication information not available"

Here is my /etc/httpd/conf.d/trac.conf

```
# Replace all occurrences of /srv/trac with your trac root below
# and uncomment the respective SetEnv and PythonOption directives.
<LocationMatch /cgi-bin/trac\.f?cgi>
    SetEnv TRAC_ENV /data/trac/msf
</LocationMatch>
<IfModule mod_python.c>
<Location /cgi-bin/trac.cgi>
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
    PythonOption TracEnv /data/trac/msf
</Location>
<Location /cgi-bin/trac.cgi/login>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Trac"
   AuthUserFile /data/trac/msf/trac.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

From reading the trac documentation I thought this should work but am having no joy. Can anyone suggest what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what my original problem was but was able to get up and running by following the instructions on using trac with mod_python directly in [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=184496&highlight=trac) post on the Fedora Forums.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /data/trac/msf/trac.htpasswd file exists, is in proper format and can be readable by everyone(or at least by the user which is runing Apache Server).

Comment: Can confirm that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

i think  you missing something, here is my config from working server

```
    <Location />
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
    PythonOption TracEnv /home/XXX/trac/
    PythonOption TracUriRoot /
</Location>
<Location /login>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "TRAC"
    AuthUserFile /home/XXX/trac/conf/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```